# How to detect popup window close event

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

#### javascript

```
document.querySelector('#share').onclick = function () {
    var popup = window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com', '', "width=400, height=400");

    popup.onbeforeunload = function() {
        alert('unload');
    }

    return false;
};
```

#### HTML

```
<a id="share" href="#">share</a>
```

Two things:

1. I want to do something after user finish the facebook share thing, if I share the page by open window the window will be auto close after everything is done, so I want to use `beforeload` event to imitate `after sharing callback`, but I can't get it when popup is closed.
2. If user just turn off the window or cancel sharing will also trigger the event, so it's not the best solution, is there any facebook sharing successful callback api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work due to cross domain calls. To get the unload event you need to call a popup instead, which has the wanted url in an iframe.

```
document.querySelector('#share').onclick = function(){
    var popup = window.open('popup.html', '', "width=400, height=400");

    popup.onbeforeunload = function(){
        console.log('unload');
    }
};
```

popup.html

```
<iframe src = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com'></iframe>
```

Comment: When I try to load sharer.php inside iframe it says in console: `Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmy-page' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
final.js:27 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.` So apparently it wont work this way..

Comment: @Lev Lukomsky: That was not the question. The popup does not solve the CORS issue, it merely helped to capture the `onbeforeunload()` event as requested - which worked. It not working a year later anymore is a different issue.

Answer (score 33):

Solved this problem with `setInterval`:

```
document.querySelector('#share').onclick = function () {
    var popup = window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com', '', "width=400, height=400");

    var popupTick = setInterval(function() {
      if (popup.closed) {
        clearInterval(popupTick);
        console.log('window closed!');
      }
    }, 500);

    return false;
};
```

Comment: This solution is working even with popups opening pages from another domain.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small javascript plugin for that functionality and without the limitation of same domain.

It has some more functionality, like ability to open the popup with a post and other small stuff.

Hope people looking for an answer find it useful.

https://github.com/enhancv/popup-tools